# Measuring the space that text takes up when it extends past the boundaries of the div

Tags: javascript, css

I've been relentlessly trying to resize the text of my buttons to fit within the parent div, and have had no success with fitty and other external plug-ins which work inconsistently or not at all.

I'm attempting to make my own simplified version that simply reduces the font-size of my answer_button_1_text element by 1px until it's smaller than the parent answer_button_1 element.

Using clientWidth returns 281 for answer_button_1 and 253 for answer_button_1_text regardless of if the text in the button extends past the boundaries.

How can I get the actual length of the text?

I've attempted to use the canvas.measureText method, but am unfamiliar with using canvases and when I apply a canvas to the entire HTML in this codepen, none of the elements on my screen are visible. I'm sure I'm making a basic mistake, but if anyone could help me find a way to return the actual space that my answer_button_1_text element takes up, I would really appreciate it.

Here is a codepen:

https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/oNWpZrg

Here is my code:

```
<button id="button" class="button lower-button">
  <div id="button_text">Really long button</div>
</button>

<div id="question_text">Test</div>
```

```
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 20%;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: black; /*Button Color*/
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-family: open_sans;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-size: min(6vw, clamp(1rem, 4.5vh, 4rem));
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0.1em 0.2em black;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.lower-button {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#question_text {
  position: absolute;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```
const question_text = document.getElementById('question_text')

let text_var = button.clientWidth + ' ' + button_text.clientWidth

question_text.innerText = text_var
```

Comment: idk much about canvas either, but it claims to be some form of an answer here:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_measuretext.asp
I was hoping you could measure the offsetWidth of the elements, it could be worth a shot (instead of clientWidth)

Comment: @iamword thanks but that's one of the links I've read already when trying to figure out canvas. I did already try offsetWidth and updated my codepen, but the values are static at 285 and 253 regardless of how long the text string is.

Comment: There's an awful lot of code for us to look through, please could you extract just the relevant stuff to make a working snippet which we can try for ourselves. [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth I updated my code with a minimally reproducible example, thank you.

Comment: Your button text div has `display: block` (all divs do, by default) which takes up all available width.  Try adding display: inline (or inline-block) to the css for the button text divs -- that should make them only as wide as the text itself.  You should also be able to see the widths easily using Chrome devtools element inspector instead of having to output the widths with JS.

Comment: @James I changed block to inline-block in the codepen and as you can see there's no difference regardless of if I target clientWidth, offsetWidth, getClientRect(), etc. The text within my elements is constantly changing so it's necessary to use Javascript to get the values since I'll be using it to resize the text contained within the buttons.